# Append "i" element with "j" element with "k" element in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, vector, append

I have 3 arrays that correspond to coordinates and data of a sparse matrix:

```
cx=[3, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
rx=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
data=[0.73646372, 0.42238729, 0.20987735, 0.33721646, 0.66935198, 0.13533819, 0.64143482, 0.004114]
```

And I need this output:

```
[[3, 0 , 0.73646372],
 [4, 0 , 0.42238729],
 [3, 1 , 0.20987735],
 ....
```

I have tried `.append()` with no luck :(

Comment: These are lists, not arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip()`

```
new = [list(i) for i in zip(cx,rx,data)]
```

output

```
[[3, 0, 0.73646372], [4, 0, 0.42238729], [3, 1, 0.20987735], [0, 2, 0.33721646], [1, 2, 0.66935198], [2, 2, 0.13533819], [1, 3, 0.64143482], [2, 4, 0.004114]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `zip` method?

```
cx=[3, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
rx=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
data=[0.73646372, 0.42238729, 0.20987735, 0.33721646, 0.66935198, 0.13533819, 0.64143482, 0.004114]
new_list=[]
for i in zip(cx, rx,data):
    print(list(i))
```

However, if you want a traditional solution:

```
cx=[3, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
rx=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
data=[0.73646372, 0.42238729, 0.20987735, 0.33721646, 0.66935198, 0.13533819, 0.64143482, 0.004114]
new_list=[]
for i,j in enumerate(cx):
    new_list.append([cx[i],rx[i],data[i]])
print(new_list)
```

More compact solutions

```
k=[list(i) for i in zip(cx, rx,data)]
j=[[cx[i],rx[i],data[i]] for i,j in enumerate(cx)]
```

Comment: Wow! i didn't think it that way... Thanks!